# Antivirus slows down tomcat based application

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, web-applications, antivirus

*I have java based application embedded with tomcat 8. When antivirus is turned on my app is very slow assuming that is slowed down by the antivirus scanning the tomcat files. I don't have permission to configure the antivirus.*

Sorry for the unclear question.
The main problem is that configuring the antivirus is not an option. This problem happens with different antivirus programs so the problem is not a specific antivirus program.

I would like to know if there is a workaround for this problem. Is there a way to configure the tomcat so it wont be a problem to the antivirus or is there a place on the server where we could put the app that the antivirus program wont scan(By default)

Comment: I'm not sure how we can help you. If you have determined that the antivirus is the culprit, then you've found the source of the problem, and you'll have to work with the person in charge of it to work out a solution. If you want help with configuring the antivirus, you can probably ask a question on SuperUser.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question

Comment: You can usually whitelist files and tell the AV system "ignore these files". Have you tried something like that?

Answer (score 0):

With the information you support to us it is very difficult to answer this question. I assume you have verified that it is definetly the Antivirus which causes your problem (In the taskmanager for example)

The way I would go is (assuming you work in a company which restricts access to the Antivirus settings) Open a Ticket or contanct your System Admin. This is definitley the easiest way, because your System Admin could offer an exception for the signature of your Tomcat App etc.

If that doesnt work out you should go the offical way with your supervisor in case you really have to.

If you need any further assistance please provide us with the basic information like your computers specs, the antivirus used.

Together with your IT Department you could offer a sample to the Antivirus provider to let them look up the details and maybe offer a fix for all users.